# AWS SAM - House-keeping the published files in s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I'm using Visual Studio to publish AWS SAM. Every published will generate a *.zip and *.template files in s3. After some times, the number of files grows.

Since the filenames are all random strings, and it doesn't allow us to give some meaningful filenames, how are you guys doing the house-keeping?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable lifecycle rules in the bucket to wipe them out automatically. Since every deployment has own random name, there is no need to keep them.

If you ever need to re-deploy, then you can either:

1. Handle upload on your own and in SAM template already point to S3 location you upload.
2. Keep the deployable package artifact in some repository and re-use it.

Comment: I need to support older version, therefore, using lifecycle rules might not be a good idea.

Comment: Also, like you mentioned, the only way I could think of is to create my own deployment package, but AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-dotnet-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) doesn't suggest this method

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/serverless_app.html - you just specify your deployment package with `s3://...` URI instead of pointing local files (which delegates packaging to SAM).